# Format the image position and make images clickable in HTML?

Tags: html

I am working on web application, where I use HTML. The expected flow is as follow-
[image: Expected Flow]

The current flow is as follow-
[image: Current Flow]

The HTML code is as follow-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Óbuda Bank-direkt Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" type="text/css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="logo_oe.png" alt="OBUDA Bank" align="left" width="70" height="70"  />
        <h2>Óbuda Online Banking</h2>

        <form method="get" action="helloSession" >
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Text 1</legend>
                  <img src="img1.png" alt="image 1" align="left" width="120" height="120"  />
      <figcaption>Caption 1</figcaption>
                  <img src="img2.png" alt="image 2" align="left" width="120" height="120"  />
      <figcaption>Caption 2</figcaption>
                  <img src="img3.png" alt="image 3" align="left" width="120" height="120"  />
      <figcaption>Caption 3</figcaption>
        <img src="img4.png" alt="image 4" align="left" width="120" height="120"  />
     <figcaption>Caption 4</figcaption>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </fieldset>

    </form>  </body>
</html>
```

When user click on the button, it will navigate to the new dynamic page created by servlet. But I want same operation, when user click on the image.

As i am in new in HTML, I want know how-

1. To format the image position
2. To make image clickable so that it navigate to new web page.

   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put the image tag inside anchor tags

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to generate a set of CSS libraries that will format your picture and show it how you want it.
You can add other properties to it, like filters, shades, etc when people hover on it.
Then make sure you include the style class on the  that contains the picture you want to format.
Working with divisions is a better approach than formatting each picture each time.
Hope it helps. Regards, DH

Comment: One of set every image in the context of other images in CSS?